# Parallel processing implementation

Tags: linux, bash, shell, postgresql, parallel-processing

I received an very old program in my company that need to be refactored. The code is a bunch of SQL instructions that are orchestred by a program written as shell commands with the objective of doing stuff with large spatial datasets.

In the middle of the shell commands, there's this implementation (below), lauching several psql processes, theoretically in parallel. I never seen this before.

The code gets this parameter numProc, which is the number of processes that will be launched.

The documentation says the numProc is the number of cores available in the machine.

This for loop iterates over slices of a relation in the postgresql database and then inserts everything into a new table.

The var_proc is used to slice the relation, so it is not the point here.

```
    for ((i=0; i < ${numProc}; i++))
    do
        psql -U $userName -h $databaseServer -d $databaseName -p $portNumber -v var_num_proc=$numProc -v var_proc=$i -f procedure.sql &
    done
    wait
fi
```

So, is it really parallelization ? Is it a efficient way of doing this (assuming that are CPU bound tasks which require a lot of memory) ?

Comment: How would be the proper manner of lauching parallel processes in this case?

Comment: @PedroCoutinho The 100-core system used as the database server means that the server can handle many multiple queries simultaneously.  Not a waste of resources. The is a completely different question from can you do multiple updates to the same database independently. That depends on  your database design, the table locking, and your particular sql statements. Ask your DBA for advice on the database schema and your procedures.

Comment: While this is on topic here, I wonder if you would get better respinses on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hey doneal24 and davidgo, thanks for the answers. The question was about the processes cooordination and syntax on a unix SO rather than about databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. This is really Parellisation.

The "&" at the end if the PSQL command backgrounds that command, so multiple commands can be launched in parellel.  The "wait" command waits until all the commands finish completing.

It is likely a reasonable way of doing this - although my guess is designed for old versions of Postgres.  Less ancient versions allow tuning of the database to allow single queries to make much better use of parellization and multiple cores which might be better depending on the logic in the procedure.

You can somewhat check this on the server by looking at the number of simultaneous psql commands being run (eg using ps) and looking at the load on the server - if its making good use of the cpus the load should be way above 1 (the closer to the number of threads the better).

If you are a glutton for punishment or have a testbed, compare the execution times with and without the &